# how to do not update value on update function?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i want this code should not be run if user call upate route code

```
if($getDistanceValue * 1000 > 300){
        if($chk_ord == 0)
        {
        $order->chk_ord_vst = 1;
        }
        elseif($chk_ord != 0){
        $order->chk_ord_vst = $chk_ord + 1;
        }
        }
        elseif($getDistanceValue * 1000 <= 300 ){
            if($chk_ord >= 4){
             $order->chk_ord_vst = 2;
            }
            elseif($chk_ord == 3){
             $order->chk_ord_vst = 2;
            }
            elseif($chk_ord == 2){
             $order->chk_ord_vst = 1;
            }
            elseif($chk_ord <= 1){
             $order->chk_ord_vst = 0;
            }   
        }
```

i am using a same fucntion to update or store order but on update i donot want to run above code i know it is very simple but i am a student and learning help me here it is controller function first user create order the if wants to update then we use get function to pass value to edit view and then pass again to stor function

```
public function storeOrder(Request $request , $update = null , $customer_id){

    $order = !is_null($update) ? Order::find($update) : new Order();
    
    $cus_det = explode("-", $request->customer_id);

    $tt_amount = array_sum($request->amount) + $request->old_balance;
    if(is_null ($update))
    $balance = $tt_amount + $request->old_balance;
   
    $auth_id = Auth::id();
    if(Auth::user()->role == 4){
        $auth_id = Customer::where('user_id', $auth_id)->first()->created_by;
    }

    $order->customer_id = $cus_det[0];
    $order->user_id = Auth::id();
    $order->ot_id = !is_null($update) ? $order->ot_id : $auth_id;
    $order->unit = array_sum($request->unit);
    $order->amount = $tt_amount;
    $order->subtotal = array_sum($request->amount);
    $order->order_comments  = $request->order_comments;
    
    if( Auth::user()->role == 5){
        $order->location_url_ot = $request->location_url_ot;
    $order->received_amount = 0;
    }
    else{
        $order->received_amount = $request->received_amount;
        
    }
    $order->discount = $request->discount;
    $order->order_date= date('Y/m/d', strtotime($request->order_date));
    if($tt_amount >= $request->received_amount){
        $order->amount_left = ($tt_amount -  $request->received_amount - $request->discount);
    }
    else{
        $order->advance = $request->received_amount - $tt_amount;
        $order->amount_left = $request->old_balance -  $request->received_amount - $request->discount;
    }
    
    $checkB = $this->checkMinBalance($cus_det[0] , $order->amount_left);
    if($checkB){
        return redirect()->back()->with('error' , 'Customer Balance Limit Exceeded ( Limit is '.$checkB.' )');
    }
    if($request->has('important')){
        $order->is_important=1;
    }
    
     if($request->has('urgent')){
        $order->urgent = urgent ;
    }
    $getothomDistanceValue = ($this->getothomDistance($order) * 1.37);
    
    $getDistanceValue = ($this->getDistance($order) * 1.37);
    
    
    $old_order = Order::where('customer_id' , $order->customer_id)->orderBy('id' , 'desc')->get();
      $chk_ord = $old_order[0]->chk_ord_vst; 

    if($getDistanceValue * 1000 > 300){
        if($chk_ord == 0)
        {
        $order->chk_ord_vst = 1;
        }
        elseif($chk_ord != 0){
        $order->chk_ord_vst = $chk_ord + 1;
        }
        }
        elseif($getDistanceValue * 1000 <= 300 ){
            if($chk_ord >= 4){
             $order->chk_ord_vst = 2;
            }
            elseif($chk_ord == 3){
             $order->chk_ord_vst = 2;
            }
            elseif($chk_ord == 2){
             $order->chk_ord_vst = 1;
            }
            elseif($chk_ord <= 1){
             $order->chk_ord_vst = 0;
            }
            
            
        }

    $order->save();

}
```

Comment: If you don't want the code to run on update then you shouldn't call/implement it in your update method.

Comment: send a param or something to check you are updating . then do a check if that parameter  or key is coming then update else store

Comment: i am using same function to update or store value

Comment: Is this all part of your **controller**? Why not put that into a seperate service which you can put under test, and call that service only under the conditions which you want to apply?

Comment: by the way my issue is resolved but actually i am using a same function to store and update value thanx for contribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I get from your question is you are using the same `storeOrder` function for storing and updating an order.
When you are using it for update, You need the id from $request->id or any other parameter from the front-end so that you can find that specific Order and then call update(). If you get the $id, You can just check if the order exists or not like below:

```
$order_exists = Order::find($request->id);
if(!isset($order_exists))
{
    if($getDistanceValue * 1000 > 300){
    if($chk_ord == 0)
    {
    $order->chk_ord_vst = 1;
    }
    elseif($chk_ord != 0){
    $order->chk_ord_vst = $chk_ord + 1;
    }
    }
    elseif($getDistanceValue * 1000 <= 300 ){
        if($chk_ord >= 4){
         $order->chk_ord_vst = 2;
        }
        elseif($chk_ord == 3){
         $order->chk_ord_vst = 2;
        }
        elseif($chk_ord == 2){
         $order->chk_ord_vst = 1;
        }
        elseif($chk_ord <= 1){
         $order->chk_ord_vst = 0;
        }   
    }
}
```

// then $order->save() when done

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this would be to pass a parameter through the form and check.

But if you have route names defined, you could also do something like:

```php
if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::current()->getName() === 'orders.create'){
    // logic here
}
```

However, I must say that I consider the later solution an anti-pattern.